# How to specify the AdditionalLibraryDirectories to msbuild?

Tags: command-line, msbuild

I'm dealing with a `.vcxproj` file with the following `Link` segment:

```xml
    <Link>
      <OutputFile>$(OutDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)</OutputFile>
      <SuppressStartupBanner>true</SuppressStartupBanner>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>..\lib;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
      <AssemblyDebug>
      </AssemblyDebug>
      <ProgramDatabaseFile>$(OutDir)$(TargetName).pdb</ProgramDatabaseFile>
      <SubSystem>Console</SubSystem>
      <RandomizedBaseAddress>false</RandomizedBaseAddress>
      <DataExecutionPrevention>
      </DataExecutionPrevention>
      <TargetMachine>MachineX86</TargetMachine>
      <ImageHasSafeExceptionHandlers>false</ImageHasSafeExceptionHandlers>
    </Link>
```

It would seem, I should be able to add more elements to the linker's `LIBPATH` by simply adding one more argument to `msbuild`'s command line: `/p:AdditionalLibraryDirectories=D:\Foo\lib`. Unfortunately, this seems ignored and `link.exe` is invoked with only the `/LIBPATH:..\lib` argument...

If I edit the file and replace the `%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)`-part with the desired path, things work -- linker is invoked with two `/LIBPATH:` arguments and the executable gets built.

Why can't I specify it as property on command-line, though?

I'm using Visual Studio 2017, with `msbuild` announcing itself as "Build Engine version 15.9.21+g9802d43bc3".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use a completely separate MSBuild property.

For example, on your command line:

```
msbuild ... /p:FooLibDir=..\lib
```

and in the project file:

```
<AdditionalLibraryDirectories>$(FooLibDir);%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
```

The reason that setting `AdditionalLibraryDirectories` on the command line doesn't work, is that the `/p` command line option for MSBuild sets properties, whereas `AdditionalLibraryDirectories` is metadata on the `Link` item (note how the parent of the `AdditionalLibraryDirectories` tag is a `Link` tag, not `PropertyGroup`).

The way to think about the difference is:

- A property is a global variable accessible to everything (hence it can be set on the command line).
- Metadata is specific to a single item (e.g., what additional directories to search for libs in, when linking this specific `.obj`).
- Metadata in a `ItemDefinitionGroup` becomes a "template" that each instance of that item will use when declared.